# C++, проверка итератора на конечную позицию без родительного контейнера

Tags: c++, итераторы

Как проверить итератор на факт того, что он указывает в конец контейнера, если неизвестно, в какому контейнеру этот итератор принадлежит?

Comment: Формально - никак.

Comment: Никак. Указатели - тоже итераторы, например. Их же никак не проверить.

Comment: Написать свой итератор, производный от существующего. В этом своем итераторе завести свойство bool, которое устанавливается в true, когда итератор доползает до конца контейнера. Потом проверять это свойство.

Comment: Можно вместе с ним передавать итератор на конец контейнера и сравнивать с ним,  как делают куча алгоритмов из стандартной библиотеки.